# How do you round down to the nearest multiple of 20in Java?

Tags: java, math, rounding

Please keep in mind I only want to round DOWN to the nearest multiple of 20, never up.

- 22    --> 20
- 45    --> 40
- 69.5  --> 60
- 60 --> 60

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO wont write code for you or try to share idea where you dont put effort.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One solution would be to subtract the results of modulo 20 (which is the remainder from division by 20) from the initial value. Something like,

```
double[] in = { 22, 45, 69.5, 60 };
for (double d : in) {
    int v = (int) d;
    v -= v % 20;
    System.out.printf("%.1f --> %d%n", d, v);
}
```

Output is

```
22.0 --> 20
45.0 --> 40
69.5 --> 60
60.0 --> 60
```

Answer (score 12):

```
public static Integer round20(Integer b){
        return b - (b%20);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can divide by 20, round (Math.floor) and multiply by 20 then.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the modulo operation. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation):

> In computing, the modulo operation finds the remainder of division of
>   one number by another (sometimes called modulus).

So you could write:

```
int unrounded = 66;
int rounded = unrounded - (unrounded % 20);
```

As a method:

```
public static int moduloFloor(int toRound, int modulo) {
    return toRound - (toRound % modulo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to know how many 20s go into the provided number. Assuming `x` is your input, try this:

```
Math.floor(x / 20) * 20
```

Comment: This is a more expensive approach than the `x - (x % 20)` answers given (subtraction is cheaper/faster than multiplication).  Also, Math.floor() is slow.